# Как вывести json на страниу в js?

Tags: javascript, json

Есть код :

```
var ul = document.getElementById('products'),
        docfrag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
        products = [
    {
    name: "test1",
    price: 240
  },
  {
    name: "test2",
    price: 250
  },
  {
    name: "test3",
    price: 260
  },
  {
    name: "test4",
    price: 270
  },
  {
    name: "test5",
    price: 280
  },
  {
    name: "test6",
    price: 290
  }
];

products.forEach(function(e) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.textContent = '<br>' + e.name + ' ' +e.price;
  docfrag.appendChild(div);

});

ul.appendChild(docfrag);

products.forEach(function(e) {
  if(e.price == 250) alert(e.name); return;
});
<div id="products">

</div>
```

Как сделать так что бы те `<br>` выводились не как текст  а именно переносили строку?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

вы записываете данные в div, как текст, а вам надо воспользоваться innerHTML

```
div.innerHTML = '<br>' + e.name + ' ' +e.price;
```

Comment: А точно, спасибо )

Comment: да не за что :)

Comment: @splash58 пометь ответ как правильный, если он тебе подошел

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев я даже не знаю, что и ответить :) пробовал, не получается :)))

Comment: @splash58 тьфу ты, не тому написал :D

Comment: @arthru пометь ответ как правильный, если он тебе подошел